# Is it possible to switch between voices using SSML tags when doing text-to-speech on Windows?

Tags: windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I have Windows 7 with several Ivona voices (harposoftware.com) installed. I have an app that starts SpVoice from Sapi and makes it read a text. Now I also have a piece of text that I'd like to turn into a dialog between multiple voices.

Previously, to change between voices, my app had to cut a text into phrases and speak each phrase individually, selecting the required voice for it.

I was wondering if there is a better solution.

So, is it possible to embed some SSML tags in my text to enable switching between voices on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`<voice>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.1) element to change voices on SAPI 5.3.

Make sure the call to Speak() has the `SPF_PARSE_SSML` flag set.

Note that the name attribute in the `<voice>` tag is processor dependent, and can't have embedded spaces.  (E.g., `<voice required="Name=Microsoft Mark">` will definitely not do what you expect.)

This is described in the W3C specification, but it's easy to miss.

There's a much better description of how the voice tag works in [this document](https://www.clarosoftware.com/help/using-microsoft-xml-tags-with-sapi5/) by Claro Software.